# Script to check if folder exists, if not, run a exe file

Tags: vba, vb6, vbscript

I need this script to look for a folder in

c:\windows\system32\foldername.

If this folder exists then i want the script to stop. If the folder does not exist then i want the script to run a .exe file from the server toinstall a piece of software. ie

\servername\folder\software.exe.

There will be file sin the folder in c:\windows\system32\foldername but i only wnat it to look at the folder not its contents.

Any suggestions please.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could try the following script

```
Option Explicit

Private Const Folder As String = "c:\windows\system32\foldername"
Private Const FileToRun As String = "\\servername\folder\software.exe"

Sub Run(ByVal sFile)
    Dim shell
    Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    shell.Run Chr(34) & sFile & Chr(34), 1, False
    Set shell = Nothing
End Sub

Dim fs
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not fs.FolderExists(Folder) Then
   Run FileToRun
End If
```